# Throwing Informative error messages out of Jersey RESTful Web-Services

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

I've got a RESTful Web-Service that does some IO and database activity in order to return a result.

There are some `Exceptions` that I would like to see, ie exception thrown because an expected variable is not set, or my database is no longer exists, etc...

However when I throw these exceptions they get caught and wrapped in a `HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)` exception and that is what the client gets (As opposed to the root exception).

I would like to see my exception here, instead of going to have to look through the Application server logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement an ExceptionMapper that returns anything you want. So, for example, it can put the whole exception with the stacktrace to the response.

Is it what you want at client side? I'm not sure.
It can be quite a difficult job for a client to rebuild the exceptions and rethrow it.

In addition, it's quite unsecure, since the stacktrace will expose the server's internal code to the client.

I suggest you declare some server error codes that make sense to client and that you want to expose. Example:

- 1000 - connection to database failed.
- 2000 - something else

So for specific exceptions, in the ExceptionMapper you can map the server exceptions to error codes and then remap them at the client side.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I mainly want it is a development and debugging tool, but there are some corner cases where I want to do exactly what you are suggesting with the error codes.